# Ajax Updater OnBlur with Prototype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype

I have an example Ajax Updater searching for the `album_art` called "Album".

```
<input name="album" id="album" type="text" value="<%= @song.album %>" onblur="new Ajax.Updater('album_cover', ('/setup/album_art?name=Album'), { asynchronous: true, evalScripts: true }); return false;">
```

How can I make this search for the current text value of the `input album`?

```
('/setup/album_art?name=' + $("album").value()) # didn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its' 'getValue' and not 'value'. Try this:

```
('/setup/album_art?name=' + $("album").getValue())
```